# Cumulative sum of a numpy array and store each value into a new array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array `fs` by reading from a *.csv file. It's size is (606,) and the data type is float64.

Example a my raw data

```
i   M(i)    dM(i)
1   0.0012  0.00013
2           0.00015
3           0.00016
4           0.00018
```

Now every element of my array should be calculated like this: `M(i) = M(i-1) + dM(i-1)*t`.

t is a constant factor of 10.

`M(2)` would be `M(2) = M(1) + dM(1)*t = 0.0012 + 0.00013*10 = 0.0025`
`M(3)` would be `M(3) = M(2) + dM(2)*t = 0.0025 + 0.00015*10 = 0.004`

I calculated some values manually.

```
i   M(i)    dM(i)
1   0.0012  0.00013
2   0.0025  0.00015
3   0.004   0.00016
4   0.0056  0.00018
```

My idea was simply to write a for loop for every item in the array, but the calculations seem to be wrong. fs is the array and `t` is a certain time interval. `t` is constant and has a value of 10

```
#   Ms(t)
def mass(t, fs):
    M_st = 0
    for i in fs
        M_st = M_st + i*t
    return M_st
```

```
sum = mass(10,fs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built in function `cumsum` for it (`a` is your array):

```
a.cumsum()
#[ 1  4  8 13 19 26]
```

***UPDATE***:
Based on OP's edit on post (`t` is scalar and `M` and `dM` are arrays. Note that python indexing is zero-based and **NOT** one-based):

```
M(0) + (dM*t).cumsum()
```

Comment: Sorry but it does not include the `t`.

Comment: @hobbicon What is `t` supposed to be? It is unclear from your code and explanation in question. Could you please edit/comment on what it is? From code it looks like you multiply values by it but from explanation seems like you want to add every `t` index?

Comment: `t` is a constant factor of 10

Comment: Well, it seems to work, but honestly I don't fully understand it. So `M(0)` is obviously the starting value and the cumsum() function iterates over `dM*t`?

Comment: @hobbicon Yeah, You got it. `dM*t` is simple multiplication of all values in `dM` by `t` and `cumsum` is cumulative sum (the sum that you need)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the file line by line, and append the current line's value plus the value of the previous element in the result array. I'm not an expert with numpy arrays, but something like this would work for a standard list

```
def create_sum_array(input_arr, length): 
   temp_arr = []
   for i in range(length):
     if(temp_arr = []):
       temp_arr.append(input_arr[i])
     else:
       temp_arr.append(temp_arr[i-1] + input_arr[i])
   return temp_arr
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not the most elegant solution, but something like this would work:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
array2 = np.zeros(len(array))
for i in range(len(array)):
    if i == 0:
        array2[i] = array[i]
        
    array2[i] = np.sum(array[:i+1]) 
print(array2)
```

Comment: How do I include the `t` factor?
Like this? `array2[i] = np.sum(array[:i*t+1]) `

Answer (score 0):

one elegant solution would be

```
m = arr[0]
temp = np.tril(np.ones([m, m]))

new_arr = temp @ arr
```